# How to squash squashed migration in django?

Tags: django, django-models

For example, I have 50 migrations and i have squashed all the migrations to 0001_initial.py and after reaching again 50 migrations. How do i squash the migrations?

Comment: Do you get an error when you try re-squashing them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before you can squash your new migrations, you need to transition your squashed migrations into normal migrations as outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) (at the end of the section):

> You must then transition the squashed migration to a normal migration
> by:
>
> - Deleting all the migration files it replaces.
> - Updating all migrations that depend on the deleted migrations to depend on the squashed migration instead.
> - Removing the **replaces** attribute in the **Migration**
>   class of the squashed migration (this is how Django tells that it is a
>   squashed migration).

Once you have removed the original migrations that were squashed, along with all references, the squashed migrations become the "normal" migrations, and you will be able to squash these again.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py squashmigrations <appname> <squashfrom> <squashto>
python manage.py help squashmigrations
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have already squashed once, your squash file contains this code.

```
replaces = [('model_name', '0001_auto...
```

2. After commenting the code above.

```
# replaces = [('model_name', '0001_auto...
```

3. you can squash again.

```
python manage.py squashmigrations app_name 000x
```